# An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
    DECLARE  @TopicsFilterFranchiseId INT 

 DECLARE @tblTopics AS table    
 (    
  ClientCategoryID int,    
  CategoryID int,    
  ProductID int    
 )   


     INSERT INTO @tblTopics 
     SELECT  @TopicsFilterFranchiseId = ID from dbo.GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@FranchiseID)
    while @TopicsFilterFranchiseId is not null
       begin
         EXEC SBS_G_GetTopicsByFranchiseID @TopicsFilterFranchiseId  
         Set @TopicsFilterFranchiseId = NULL 
       end
```

I got this error please tell me how can I resolve this error

Comment: The error message is telling you what is wrong here. Your select statement is assigning a value to a variable and therefore cannot populate a table. Your select statement also has to return the same number of values as the Insert requires (In this case 3)

Comment: Yup I know about the error what is the solution for this

Comment: You will need to seperate the assign variable from the select into.  Make it two different statements.  You are trying to insert 3 values into a table, what does GetIDsTableFromIDsList return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO @tblTopics 
SELECT  @TopicsFilterFranchiseId = ID from dbo.GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@FranchiseID)
```

Above code is not valid.

Rather have select statement that has value/columns to insert.

E.g

```
INSERT INTO @tblTopics 
SELECT  @ClientCategoryID,@CategoryId,@Productid
```

Assign value to variable before insert statement, you can not assign value to variable and insert into table in the same statement.